# How do i fix Ambiguous column name 'Venue_code'. error

Tags: sql

This is my SQL code where I'm creating a join.

Now when I run it, I get an error:

> Ambiguous column name 'Venue_code'

How do I fix this?

```
 SELECT 
     Venue_name, Customer_name, Checkin_date, nights
 FROM
     Venues, Customers, Accomodation_booking
 WHERE
     Venues.Venue_code = Accomodation_booking.Venue_code
     AND Customers.Customer_ID = Accomodation_booking.Customer_ID
     AND Venue_code Code = 'V0001';
```

Comment: Presumably more than one of your tables has a column called `Venue_code`, so the query needs to know which once you're referring to.  Prefix it with the table name, exactly like you already do everywhere else that you refer to that column in the `WHERE` clause...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

The last line looks suspicious. If you meant `Venue_code = 'V0001'` then remove `Code` and change `Venue_code` to either `Venues.Venue_code` or `Accomodation_booking.Venue_code`.

You probably had difficulties because you use SO for the first time. The code does not look clean. Remove the `enter code here` part too (end of second line).

Answer (score 0):

If you join two (or more) tables and one or more column names are used in more than one table you need to prefix it but you didn't do it in your last line. It seems there is more than one error

```
AND Venue_code  Code = 'V0001';
```

did you mean?

```
AND Venues.Venue_code = 'V0001';
```